# How to create and configure the custom UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper in Spring security 3.0.5?

Tags: spring-security, customization

I am using spring security 3.0.5 in my web application based on Spring MVC. We need to check four parameters for the authentication i.e. username, password, company and organization.

For this I have written my own custom authentication token which encapsulates these four fields. I also have a custom user details service.

Normal UserDetails service has loadUserByUsername(username) but in my case I need this method to accept all the four parameters. For this I have decided to provide custom implementation of UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper which calls loadUserByUsername(username).

In my custom implementation I will pass whole authentication object instead of just the username.

I am not getting how do i plugin my custom UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper  in the spring security xml file.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating 'your own' `UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper` you'll want to implement `AuthenticationUserDetailsService` instead. This class can then be injected with the following Spring Security configuration:

```
<bean id="preAuthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="yourAuthenticationUserDetailsService" />
</bean>
```